# Uncaught ReferenceError: my is not defined

Tags: webpack, ruby-on-rails-6

I am new to Rails 6 and Webpacker.

It should be really simple but I cannot find any good tutorial for it.

I am just trying to add functions in a new .js-file, but those are not found.

my application.js is:

```
require("@rails/ujs").start();
require("turbolinks").start();
require("@rails/activestorage").start();
require("channels");
require("jquery")

import * as my from 'my/custom';
```

and app/javascript/my/custom.js looks like

```
export function helloWorld() {
  alert('Hello World');
}
```

I would assume that I can now use `my.helloWorld()` (for example in the chrome console), but then I get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: my is not defined`.

I also tried `import {helloWorld} from 'my/custom';` but with no success

I want to use the functions later in my views.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try this implementation :-

**application.js**

```
require("@rails/ujs").start();
require("turbolinks").start();
require("@rails/activestorage").start();
require("channels");
require("jquery")

// require your custom js file
require("my/custom")
```

And then in your custom js file:-

**app/javascript/my/custom.js**

```
window.helloWorld = function helloWorld() {
  alert('Hello World');
}
```

then call this function `helloWorld()` wherever you want.

Comment: Yes, thank you that works. But isn't `import` etc. more "ES6"-y?

Comment: Yes you can also do in that way here is reference link :- https://blog.capsens.eu/how-to-write-javascript-in-rails-6-webpacker-yarn-and-sprockets-cdf990387463 
But I have always implemented like above for custom js.